# How can I show a Google profile image next to my search engine results?

Tags: seo, google-search

I just performed a Google search for the words "Google Analytics" and noticed half way down the page that there was an image next to one of the results:

[image: Google search]

How can I achieve this? Having used Yoast's plugin I know how much of a genius he is!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's how he did it: http://yoast.com/highlighting-wordpress-authors-search/

> To do this, you need to apply the authorship markup Google announced a
>   couple weeks back. This basically means adding rel="author" to a link
>   to the authors page on the same domain. My author link for this post,
>   for instance, looks like this:

```
<a rel="author" href="http://yoast.com/author/admin/"
  title="Posts by Joost de Valk">Joost de Valk</a>
```

According to [this discussion](https://plus.google.com/115369062315673853712/posts/ExGtKqT3GRx) on Google+ they only like real photos though, not cartoons.

Comment: Thanks. Ah, I was hoping to add our company icon. Ok, works well though, the search result instantly jumps off the page with an image next to it.

Comment: I applied for the authorship markup a while ago and still have nothing. I set up all the links properly with my website and google profile (confirmed using webmaster tools). Is google enabling this on a preferential basis or is it based on the popularity of the website?

Answer (score 0):

Paul is right, this is accomplished via the new rel="author" markup offered by Google.

Joost has a great technical write up on the topic but I did want to clarify that you usually need a set of three links.

- A link from the content to the author page using rel="author"
- A link from the author page to your Google Profile using rel="me"
- A link from your Google Profile to your author page using rel="me"

There is actually a streamlined way (with two links) but it seems to be less reliable at this stage, in part because the Rich Snippets Testing Tool had a bug that would produce a false negative.

For more details, including how long it may take from implementation to display, you can visit my own post on [How To Implement Rel=Author](http://www.blindfiveyearold.com/how-to-implement-rel-author).

Comment: how long does it take to implement? Its been a week and no results